# Using the name returned in DAYNAME(CURDATE()) in an expression

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column for each day of the week. I would like to use `dayname(curdate())` in an expression to get the value of the column with the name returned by `dayname(curdate())`. My idea was to use it this way:

```
CASE WHEN table.LOWER(DAYNAME(CURDATE())) = <value> THEN ...
```

This isn't working. I'd like to know the right way to do it.

The table is set up like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    client_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    monday INT,
    tuesday INT,
    wednesday INT,
    thursday INT,
    friday INT,
    saturday INT,
    sunday INT
);
```

The days of the week will have either a 0 or 1 to show if the client is normally available on these days.

Comment: You can't use an expression in place of a column name.

Comment: Could you please provide create statement for the table or table structure descriptevely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<value> = 
    CASE DAYNAME(CURDATE())
        WHEN 'Monday' THEN table.monday
        WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN table.tuesday
        WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN table.wednesday
        WHEN 'Thursday' THEN table.thursday
        WHEN 'Friday' THEN table.friday
        WHEN 'Saturday' THEN table.saturday
        WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 'table.sunday
    END
```